# Excel-generating specific number of random binaries with probabilities proportional to cell's value

Tags: excel, math, stat

I have such a matrix in an excel sheet. It has 140 cells. I want to generate 20 binaries randomly.  However, the probability of generating "1" in each cell is proportional to cell's value. Namely, most of the 1's should be generated in the top rows, since each cell's values are larger at tops.

[image]

For example one possible generated sample can be:

[image]

How can I do that in an excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your table right, you want random values in string format.

Try:

```
="0," & right("000" & RandBetween(1,500),4)
```

IF I am totally missing the boat please elaborate further on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple formula in `A21` will give you `1` with probability `A1`:

```
=IF(RAND()<A1,1,0)
```

The result is binary, so you can get the same result without `IF`

```
=--(RAND()<A1)
```

> 